# Remove rows from a dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I have a dynamically created table.  Users can click a button on the table to which puts an object into an array.  This then creates a "total" table which calculates a total price. I have remove buttons on this table but when clicked both the remove ("X") and the Remove All buttons do nothing.

Code can be found here:

http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBt2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method = "html" omit-xml-declaration = "no" doctype-system ="http://www.w3.org.TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" doctype-public = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" />

<xsl:template match = "/data-set">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Basket.css"/>
    <title> My Shopping Basket </title>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;

    var basket = [];

    // display basket and fill cells
    function displaybasket(){
      var shoppingBasketTblBody = document.getElementById(&quot;shoppingBasketTblBody&quot;);
      while(shoppingBasketTblBody.rows.length&gt;0) {
        shoppingBasketTblBody.deleteRow(0);
      }

      var basket_total = 0.00;

      //populating the table

      for(var product in basket){
        var removeButton = document.createElement('input');
        removeButton.type = 'button'; 
        removeButton.value = 'X';
        removeButton.onclick = 'removeItem(this)';

        /* could not work out how to implement without using cookies, ran out of time.
        var addButton = document.createElement('input');
        addButton.type = 'button'; 
        addButton.value = '+';
        addButton.onclick = 'addItem';

        var minusButton = document.createElement('input');
        minusButton.type = 'button'; 
        minusButton.value = '-';
        minusButton.onclick = 'minusItem;' */

        var row = shoppingBasketTblBody.insertRow();
        var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
        var cellDescription = row.insertCell(1);
        var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);
        var cellAmount = row.insertCell(3)
        var cellRemove = row.insertCell(4);

        cellPrice.align = &quot;right&quot;;
        cellName.innerHTML = basket[product].Name;
        cellDescription.innerHTML = basket[product].Description;
        cellPrice.innerHTML = &quot;£&quot;+basket[product].Price.toFixed(2);
        cellAmount.innerHTML = basket[product].Quantity;
        cellRemove.appendChild(removeButton);
        basket_total += parseFloat(basket[product].Price);
        console.log(basket_total);
      }

      // display total cost
      document.getElementById(&quot;cart_total&quot;).innerHTML=&quot;£&quot;+basket_total.toFixed(2);
    }


    function AddtoCart(name,Description,price, Quantity){
      //create product
      var item = {};
      item.Name = name;
      item.Description = Description;
      item.Price = parseFloat(price);
      item.Quantity = Quantity;

      //push to basket
      basket.push(item);
      //call display basket function
      displaybasket();
    }  

    function removeAll() {
      basket.length = 0.0;
      basket_total = 0.00;
      document.getElementById(&quot;shoppingBasketTblBody&quot;).deleteRow();
    }

    function removeItem(r) {
      var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById(&quot;shoppingBasketTblBody&quot;).deleteRow(i);
      //subtract price of item from basket_total ???
    }  

    /*could not work out how to implement without using cookies, ran out of time.
    function addItem() {

    }   

    function minusItem() {

    }*/ 

  &lt;/script&gt;
  </xsl:text> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item Number</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Description</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <xsl:for-each select="basket">
        <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="myId" select="@iId" />
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Product" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="stockLevel" />
          </td>
          <td>
            £<xsl:value-of select="price" />
          </td>
          <td>
          <button type="button" onclick="AddtoCart('{Product}','{Description}','{price}','1')">Add one to cart</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
     <table id="shoppingBasketTbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Price
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="shoppingBasketTblBody">

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="right" id="cart_total"></td>
                        <td colspan="3" align="right" id="removeAll"><button type="button" id="remove all" onclick="removeAll" > Remove All </button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="basket.xsl"?>
<data-set>
  <basket id="001">
    <Product>Shorts (F) </Product>
    <Description>Stone Wash Denim Shorts</Description>
    <stockLevel>20</stockLevel>
    <price>25.90</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="002">
    <Product>Bag (F)</Product>
    <Description>Leather Shoulder Bag</Description>
    <stockLevel>4</stockLevel>
    <price>50.45</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="003">
    <Product>Blouse (F)</Product>
    <Description>Vintage Blue Silk Polka Dot Blouse</Description>
    <stockLevel>8</stockLevel>
    <price>45.99</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="004">
    <Product>Boots (F)</Product>
    <Description>Soft Leather Brown Ankle Boots</Description>
    <stockLevel>3</stockLevel>
    <price>65.35</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="005">
    <Product>Belts (F)</Product>
    <Description>Woven Finish Fashion Belt</Description>
    <stockLevel>15</stockLevel>
    <price>21.99</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="006">
    <Product>Shirt (M)</Product>
    <Description>Jacquard Pattern Wrangler Western Shirt</Description>
    <stockLevel>19</stockLevel>
    <price>34.87</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="007">
    <Product>Shoes (M) </Product>
    <Description>Suede Ankle Boots</Description>
    <stockLevel>6</stockLevel>
    <price>55.00</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="008">
    <Product>Trousers (M)</Product>
    <Description>Izod Peach Chinos</Description>
    <stockLevel>23</stockLevel>
    <price>31.75</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="009">
    <Product>Belt (M)</Product>
    <Description>Suede Casual Belt</Description>
    <stockLevel>4</stockLevel>
    <price>22.98</price>
  </basket>
  <basket id="010">
    <Product>Hat (M)</Product>
    <Description>Trilby Style Brown Woven Fix</Description>
    <stockLevel>2</stockLevel>
    <price>67.80</price>
  </basket>
</data-set>
```

Comment: Much better to reduce your code to a minimal example that displays the issue. This will often lead you to an answer before posting, and if not, makes the job of answering much simpler. It's also much better to post the actual browser markup, not the code that generates it.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
removeButton.onclick = 'removeItem(this)';
```

simply assigns a string to the onclick property, you need to assign a function reference so:

```
removeButton.onclick = removeItem;
```

Then in the *removeItem* function, *this* will be the button:

```
function removeItem() {
  var r = this;
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex; // button -> cell -> row
  document.getElementById(&quot;shoppingBasketTblBody&quot;).deleteRow(i);
}
```

You may find it easier to remove the button using:

```
var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

to remove the dependency on *getElementById*. You're still tied to the DOM structure though.

Comment: When I change my onclick code to `removeButton.onclick = removeItem;`, everytime I add a new product to my basket it executes the function.  Is there a way to exit a function if it was not called by the user?

Comment: See my comment to your post. At the xsltransform link I see 3 blank sections. Post the code *here* in a format that can be copied and pasted into a browser. That is, post what the browser gets, not what you use to generate it unless that is what you are asking about. Address one concern at a time.